# Pandas GroupBy Reset Index not Resetting

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to reset the index on my dataframe, but the reset_index is not fully resetting the column headers. How would I adjust this to reach my desired outcome?

```
f = {'Price_x': ['count','mean','median', 'std', q1, q3]}
dfa = df.groupby(['Item','Criteria']).agg(f).reset_index()
print(list(dfa))
```

Current result:

```
[('MLS#_y', ''), ('Criteria', ''), ('Price_x', 'count'), ('Price_x', 'mean'), ('Price_x', 'median'), ('Price_x', 'std'), ('Price_x', 'q1'), ('Price_x', 'q3')]
```

Desired Result:

```
['Item','Criteria','count','mean','median', ... ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing a dictionary to `agg`, so this will result in a MultiIndex. If you didn't want that, since you're only using all these functions on a single column, you directly use:

```
dfa = df.groupby(['Item','Criteria'])['Price_x'].agg(['count','mean','median', 'std', q1, q3]).reset_index()
```

Comment: With that, I'm getting the following error: TypeError: Must provide 'func' or tuples of '(column, aggfunc)

Comment: @RCarmody sorry, it seems I edited just before you commented. Could you try what I have now?